# Pylint: Method could be a function in base class

Tags: python, inheritance, methods, pylint

I was wondering what is the best way to handle a Pylint error complaining about a situation like in this example:

```py
class Base:
    def some_funct(self) -> List:
        """
        Intended to be overwritten in child classes, but
        if not, it's ok to return an empty list
        """
        return []

class Child1(Base):
     def some_funct(self) -> List:
          # Now, this does actual stuff!!
          return [a for a in self.some_iterable]

class Child2(Base):
   # An empty list is fine for this one
   pass
```

Pylint is going to say that the `Base.safe_implementation` could be a function (which... is true, but I'd like `self` to stay there)

Is there a better solution that just marking it as `pylint: disable`? Which... I mean... if it's what it is, it is what it is and it's not a *"deal breaker"* , but if there's a better way, it'd be nice to know.

This is for Python 3.6, in case it's relevant.

Comment: Why do you have a class with only one method in the first place?

Comment: If `Base` is actually more complicated in the first place, then `pylint` can just be ignored.

Comment: @chepner: Yes, indeed. It was simplified for the example. I'll edit the question and clarify it.

Comment: I'd  just use the disable comment (though specialized to ignore *only* this specific error/warning).

Comment: If pylint's only issue is the fact that `self` isn't used, you could construct a list comprehension that will generate an empty list, like `[x for x in self.some_iterable if False]`. (That might suggest an approach where the definition uses `[x for self.some_iterable if self._predicate(x)]`, and the child class just overrides `self._predicate` rather than `some_funct` itself.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the method as a `staticmethod` to make `pylint` happy:

```py
class Base:
    @staticmethod
    def some_funct() -> List:
        """
        Intended to be overwritten in child classes, but
        if not, it's ok to return an empty list
        """
        return []
```

Since the `self` parameter is passed implicitly under normal conditions, it is not part of a method's outward signature. This allows to define the method as a `staticmethod` in the base class and still replace it with a regular method in a derived class without changing the outward behaviour.